# ¿Cómo guardar un timestamp de php en timestamp de mysql? Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, carbon

He leído un sin fin de publicaciones y no he podido solucionarlo.

En uno de mis formularios necesito preguntar una fecha, para facilitarsela al usuario se la solicito en este formato: **d/m/Y**.

En mi migración lo defino así:

```
$table->timestamp('assembly_date');
```

En el controlador lo valido así:

```
$fields = request()->validate([
            'assembly_date' =>  'required|date_format:d/m/Y',    
        ]);
```

Antes de guardarlo en DB lo convierto a timestamp así:

```
$fields['assembly_date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fields['assembly_date'])->timestamp;
```

El error que recibo es el siguiente:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1576859472' for column 'assembly_date' at row 1 (22007)
```

PD: no quiero tener que lidiar con fechas, por esa razón, solicito la fecha en el formato más fácil y la guardo en el que considero menos problemático. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Es que el timestamp de Carbón se refiere al formato timestamp de unix, y el timestamp de la migración, se refiere al de la BD. Prueba con  Carbon::
 createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fields['assembly_date'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias!